# Which scene transitions are commonly used?

Tags: video, video-editor, transitions

Video editing software offers many scene transition effects, but which ones are commonly used in movies and tv shows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commonly used transitions are cuts and dissolves. [Cuts](https://www.premiumbeat.com/blog/8-essential-cuts-every-editor-should-know/) can be edited in a variety of ways, depending on the storytelling situation, but the [straight cut](https://amirediting.blogspot.com/p/blog-page_3.html) is the most often used transition. Any other [transitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_transition) have unique purposes, but should always be motivated by the story and used sparingly. The exception to the frequency rule is when a piece adopts a transition as a stylistic device. But you need to approach that with caution, as it can [scream amateur](https://www.reddit.com/r/editors/comments/2cbtae/whats_a_overused_editing_technique_that_screams/).

Answer (score 2):

Probably fade and cut. But, I must say every transition effect have a a point in terms of story telling. 'Cut' transition tells us the next scene might be in another place and time and so on.